# Grouping by two fields on same line

Tags: sql, t-sql

Very to to this so apologies if this very basic or I miss some detail

I have the query

```
select   #FBorders1.QuestCode
    ,COUNT(Distinct #FBOrders1.CustomerID)as UniqueCust
from #FBOrders1
group by #FBOrders1.QuestCode
```

This show unique Customers to have ordered a specific stock item (QuestCode)

I now need to show how many of those unique customers have placed 2, 3 or 4 orders.. the 2nd, 3rd, 4th orders will not have a QuestCode recorded against them

Table consists of OrderID, CustomerID, QuestCode

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
select a.QuestCode ,COUNT(distinct a.CustomerID)as UniqueCust,
count(distinct  (case when a.questcode = b.questcode and  a.customerid = b.customerid then  b.customerid else 0 end) )-2,
count(distinct  (case when a.questcode = b.questcode and  a.customerid = b.customerid then  b.customerid else 0 end) )-3,
count(distinct  (case when a.questcode = b.questcode and  a.customerid = b.customerid then  b.customerid else 0 end) )-4
from fborder a inner join
fborder b on a.customerid = b.customerid
group by a.QuestCode
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That however only gives me total number of orders against a QuestCode.  What we require is How many unique customers placed an order using this QuestCode and then how many of those customers returned to place 2nd, 3rd 4th order.  The follow up orders contain no QuestCode. I have been staring at the screen for last hour & can not think how it would be done!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and desire output in sample format. That would help me having better idea and i'm sure i can give you the query

Comment: Sure.. sorry for the incomplete reply before.. I didnt not realise hitting enter would post the comment. :)

Comment: QuestCode = AAA, UniqueCusts = 150, Placed 2nd order = 75, Placed 3rd Order = 55, Placed 4th order = 30

Comment: So you want to know how many of the same user(who already placed the order for AAA) place AAA order for 2nd time, 3rd time and 4th time?

Comment: Based on my understanding, i have modified the code, please check and let me know, are you expecting this result?

Comment: give those count aggregates an alias that makes sense

Comment: Viji.. yes but now the user has come back with a modification to the request that changes the entire reasoning behind the figures... Have asked for clarification on what they actually want.  Thankyou for the help though